# hadoop command is not working

Tags: command-line, bash, hadoop

I am trying to install single node hadoop on my ubuntu 14.04 as per the documentation available at [bogotobogo.com](http://www.bogotobogo.com/Hadoop/BigData_hadoop_Install_on_ubuntu_single_node_cluster.php).
 after following all the steps when I tried to format the hadoop file system it shows permission denied
I have set $HADOOP_HOME envirnmnt in my bashrc file

```
hduser@maaz-HP-2000-Notebook-PC:/home/maaz$ hadoop namenode -format   
bash: /usr/local/hadoop/bin/hadoop: Permission denied
```

I used sudo ,but then it shows `hadoop: command not found`.

```
hduser@maaz-HP-2000-Notebook-PC:/home/maaz$ sudo hadoop namenode -format  
[sudo] password for hduser:     
sudo: hadoop: command not found
```

same thing is happening when i used the command `hadoop -version`

```
hduser@maaz-HP-2000-Notebook-PC:/home/maaz$ hadoop -version  
bash: /usr/local/hadoop/bin/hadoop: Permission denied  
hduser@maaz-HP-2000-Notebook-PC:/home/maaz$ sudo hadoop -version  
[sudo] password for hduser:   
sudo: hadoop: command not found
```

How can I solve it?
performed which hadoop but  it shows nothing

[image: screen shot after performing the command ,which hadoop & ls -lsa]

Comment: please [edit] your question with the result of `which hadoop` and afterwards perform `ls -lsa` on the result of `which hadoop`.

Comment: @Yaron thanks for replying ! question has been edited .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for the below error:

> bash: /usr/local/hadoop/bin/hadoop: Permission denied

Is that fact that you are trying to execute `/usr/local/hadoop/bin/hadoop` which it isn't execute-able.

Running the below command will make the `hadoop` file executable.

```
chmod +x /usr/local/hadoop/bin/hadoop
```

I suspect that all the files which ends with `.sh` should be executables.

The below command will turn the `.sh` files to be executables:

```
chmod +x /usr/local/hadoop/bin/*.sh
```

**Note:**

There seems to be a problem with the hadoop downloaded file / unpacking process.

I've downloaded [`hadoop-2.7.4.tar.gz`](https://archive.apache.org/dist/hadoop/core/hadoop-2.7.4/hadoop-2.7.4.tar.gz) (`binary` `tar.gz` file) from the official site.

When I test the `tar.gz` file I clearly saw that the original bin/hadoop file was execute-able (the `x` flag in the `-rwxr-xr-x` permission)

```
 tar tzvf hadoop-2.7.4.tar.gz  | grep "bin/hadoop"
-rwxr-xr-x kshvachk/eng   1360 2017-08-01 03:35 hadoop-2.7.4/sbin/hadoop-daemons.sh
-rwxr-xr-x kshvachk/eng   6452 2017-08-01 03:35 hadoop-2.7.4/sbin/hadoop-daemon.sh
-rwxr-xr-x kshvachk/eng    8786 2017-08-01 03:35 hadoop-2.7.4/bin/hadoop.cmd
-rwxr-xr-x kshvachk/eng    6488 2017-08-01 03:35 hadoop-2.7.4/bin/hadoop
```

Comment: To add to this, there are two files I saw there `source` and `binary` download the latter and it works. Just done that

Comment: @George - thanks for the comment, yes I've download the `binary` `tar.gz` file and not the `source` `tar.gz` - I'll update my answer to make it clearer